# Connecting GitHub through Tor is not working

Tags: linux, git, proxy, github, tor

I'm using GitHub through Tor because Git ports are blocked on my network.

I'm using Fedora 17 GNU Linux. Suddenly I could not connect to GitHub through Tor today. Any troubleshooting methods or suggestions?

Here is the error I get:

```
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection timed out
```

Tor is working fine. I can connect other applications to `127.0.0.1:9050` and the proxy is working fine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have setup Tor through GitHub using at assembla.com (which unfortunatley is not available now, but what you have to do is set proxy options for git and in those you have to specify the tor proxy) but found that I haven't updated my `~/.bashrc`.

something similar to this [tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/how-to-get-git-working-behind-firewall.html).

Comment: the link was available without authentication when I posted this answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this message if you haven't set your git user properties

Check to see if you have ~/.gitconfig

Then do:

```
git config --global user.name "your-user-name"
git config --global user.email your@email-address.com
```